# Automatic configuration and authentication of email account in Outlook on Office 365

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, autodiscover

When using Active Directory and Microsoft Exchange Server, upon opening, Outlook will automatically add, configure, **and authenticate** the email account of the current AD user account by use of its primary email address.

When using Active Directory, Azure AD Connect (for password synchronisation), and Office 365, upon opening, Outlook will simply prompt to add an email account. Is there any way to get Outlook to do **exactly** the same as above?

It's amazing how many users will log on to a new PC, open Outlook, see the prompt, and simply phone us to get us to remote in and guide them through typing in their email address and password. AutoDiscover alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Since, I've learned that this behaviour is called Autodiscover SCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short way:**

**Enable Office 365 modern authentication**: it won't remove the password prompt, but it'll change it to something that your end users will recognize as a sign in page and will be able to fill up their login information without getting back to helpdesk, enabled by just using a Powershell command.

**The Long way:**

**Enable Office Office 365 modern authentication and ADFS**: this will allow your users to login without typing a username/password, but it is too much to setup and operate for its value, needs a ton of things to do to enable.

References:

- https://blogs.office.com/2015/03/23/office-2013-modern-authentication-public-preview-announced/
- http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/office-365/exchange-online/exchange-online-identity-models-and-authentication-demystified-part1.html

Comment: If user training won't solve the problem, then #2 ADFS will help.  They may still get login prompts outside the internal network however.